# Not able to connect to Oracle DB from Shell Script

Tags: shell

I am having challenge connecting to Oracle DB  (Load Balanced environment - Multiple host) from Shell Script.

I tried the following in linux box directly and it's working.

> /apps/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus
>   /@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(FAILOVER = YES)
>   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname1)(PORT = 6235)) (ADDRESS =
>   (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname2)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA =
>   (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = lruata1)))'

When I tried the same from shell script (reading the db connect url from environment script) its not working.

Getting output as sqlplus parameters

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

```
-H             Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
               usage help.
-V             Displays the SQL*Plus version.
```

content from config.sh

```
oracle.base=/apps/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1
db.connect.url='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(FAILOVER = YES) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname1)(PORT = 6235)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname2)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = lruata1)))'
log.path=/apps/lriservers/bpmdbo_scripts/logs
```

Reading the key & Value in the main script

```
function getPropertyFromFile()
{
propertyName=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/\./\\\./g'`
fileName=$2;
cat $fileName | sed -n -e "s/^[ ]*//g;/^#/d;s/^$propertyName=//p" | tail -1
}

export ORACLE_BASE=`getPropertyFromFile oracle.base $CONFIG_FILE`
export CONNECT_IDENTIFIER=`getPropertyFromFile db.connect.url $CONFIG_FILE`
export LOG_PATH=`getPropertyFromFile log.path $CONFIG_FILE`

export ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_BASE}

echo "Oracle Base : "$ORACLE_BASE
echo "Connect Identifier : "$CONNECT_IDENTIFIER
echo "Log Path : "$LOG_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/lib
export SQP=${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus

LOG_FILE=$LOG_PATH/$ENV_NAME'_'$DEPLOYMENT_VERSION.log

cd $SCRIPT_HOME
CONNECT_STRING=${DB_USERNAME}/$DB_PASSWORD@${CONNECT_IDENTIFIER}


${SQP} -S  ${CONNECT_STRING} << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

SET ECHO ON;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

spool $LOG_FILE
@$SCRIPT_NAME
spool off;

EXIT
EOF
```

Regards
Balaji Subramaniam

Comment: "reading the db connect url from environment script" - can you show us that? It's easy to make an escaping mistake for shell commands, e.g. with the @. Or could you read the connection settings from tnsnames.ora or similar?

Comment: edited the text

Comment: I fixed the issue,  I was having few white spaces in the db.connect.url.  I just removed the white space and the issue has been fixed

Comment: Great! I'd guess you could also have quoted the use of ${CONNECT_STRING} in your script too then.